# Use FutureBuilder's snapshot.data in DataTable

Tags: flutter, http, dart, datatable

I'm new to Flutter, and I stuck with display data in Flutter DataTable widget.

I've try to find the simplest way to use http data in the DataTable. If it's possible I avoid to create Dart calsses for this operation, because - seemingly - the FutureBuilder's snapshot.data is the same that my "testData" which appears perfectly in the table. Thanks for your advices.

Here is my sample code:

```
fetchData() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.https('test.url', 'test/test'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    return jsonData;

  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
}

    FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.hasData) {

            var fetchedData = snapshot.data;

            var testData = [
              {"Desc": "Desc 1.", "Code": "AB"},
              {"Desc": "Desc 2.", "Code": "AC"},
              {"Desc": "Desc 3.", "Code": "AD"},
            ];

            // fetchedData and testData seemingly the same in the console
            print(fetchedData);
            print(testData);

            return DataTable(
                    columns: [
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Description')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Code')),
                    ],
                    sortColumnIndex: 1,
                    rows:
                    fetchedData // it works with "testData" but not with "fetchedData"
                        .map(
                      ((element) => DataRow(
                        cells: <DataCell>[
                          DataCell(Text(element['Desc'])),
                          DataCell(Text(element['Code'])),
                        ],
                      )),
                    ).toList(),
                  );
          } else {
            // We can show the loading view until the data comes back.
            debugPrint('Step 1, build loading widget');
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      );
```